# MVC3 CkEditor performance rendering issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, performance, rendering, ckeditor

I have an C# .Net MVC3 web app.  We are utilizing the CkEditor control.  We love the control, however we are having a performance issue with it.  One of our pages displays a dynamic list of objects.  For each row in the list we have two CkEditor text areas.  The larger the list the slower our app is.  A list of 72 rows takes over a minute and a half to lead.  The rendered page has time tags at the beginning and end of the page.  The time tags show the page takes 2 seconds to create.  The rest of the time is spent on the client rendering the page.  The performance degradation is directly proportional to the number of CkEditor controls on a page.

Any ideas?  Are we, in our code, loading a framework more than we need to, going out to the web for properties of each control?

The original developer is no longer and I am a novice with CkEditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.  It's not great news, but it's an answer.  IE is the culprit.  Firefox loads the identical URL's 6 to 7 times faster.  The attached article from CkEditor support is what clued me in

[CkEditor Support on Performance Degradation](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7208#comment:2)